# Is there a way to check the location of an element on a page in Cypress?

Tags: javascript, cypress, e2e-testing

At different CSS breakpoints elements are rendered differently on our page.

For instance, on a form, certain inputs would appear below each other on mobile, rather than adjacent to each other on desktop.

Am I trying to test CSS here, or is there a simple way in Cypress I could validate that they are displaying correctly across different devices?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what your exact question is, however here are a few things which may help you:

- it is possible in Cypress to test the website for various viewports using `cy.viewport`. Check [this documentation page](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/viewport.html#Syntax)
- if you want to get position of an element, you may use jQuery functions such as `outerWidth`, for example: `cy.get(elementSelector).invoke('outerWidth')`
- Cypress was not designed as a visual testing tool, as it is described [here in the docs](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/tooling/visual-testing.html#Functional-vs-visual-testing), however there you may find some information useful for you, for instance about [Cypress plugin for snapshots](https://github.com/meinaart/cypress-plugin-snapshots).
- if you are interested in visual regression testing, you may check out [this Cypress webinar with Happo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C_p12IvN5HU), which is a tool made just for that

I hope it helps!